# Integrate $x^x$ or prove that it is non-elementary

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I've heard that the function $x^x$ cannot be integrated but couldn't you give a Taylor series approximation of the function:  $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(x\ln x) ^{n} }{n!} $$
and then integrate the series?

If this method doesn't work how do you prove that it is non-elementary.

Comment: Many functions can be "integrated" but are not elementary, for example $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$

Comment: @David Peterson define non-elementary

Comment: A function which cannot be written in terms of elementary functions

 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Comment: Do you have an general expression for $\int (x \log(x))^n\,dx$?  And even if one is available, the integral of $x^x$ would still be expressed as a series.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for
$$I_n=\int \big[x \log(x)\big]^n\,dx=-\big[\log (x)\big]^{n+1}\, E_{-n}\big[-(n+1) \log (x)\big]$$ where appears the exponential integral fuction.

This does not look very elementary.